# how to create modal as a directive or service

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I have a modal popup, which I used, I don't know how can I create from this current modal a generic service or directive. I have build some directives in my life so I know how to build it.
I need suggestion to what to do with the following modal pop-up:

```
 <button id="GoBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">GO</button>
        <div id="blackout"></div>
        <div id="popup">
            <span class="close"></span>
            <span id="spinner" class="loading style-1"></span>
            <div id="content">
                <table id="content_table" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Source</th>
                        <th>IsValid</th>
                        <th>Sampling Date</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr ng-repeat="item in collection">
                        <td>
                            <input class="dga_radio" id="dga-radio-{{$index}}" type="radio" name="dga" value="{{$index}}" ng-model="selectedDga.index" />
                            <label for="dga-radio-{{$index}}" ><span></span></label>
                        </td>
                        <td ng-repeat="(key,value) in item">
                            {{value}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="warning-message">
                <img src="../images/sign.png" width="32px" height="32px" />
                <span id="wmessage"></span>
            </div>
            <button id="okbtn" class="btn btn-success btn-md">ok</button>
            <button id="cancelbtn" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">cancel</button>
        </div>
```

The logic himself is inside the controller:

```
$("#blackout, .close").click(function () {
        $("#blackout").removeClass("visable");
        $("#popup").removeClass("visable");
    });

    $("#GoBtn").click(function () {

        var wmessage_container = $('#warning-message');
        var wmessage = $('#warning-message > #wmessage');
        startDate = $("#datepicker-start").val();
        endDate = $("#datepicker-end").val();
        var content = $("#content");
        console.log('reach here!');
        $scope.collection = [];
        if ((angular.isDefined(startDate) && startDate != '') && (angular.isDefined(endDate) && endDate != '')) {
            console.log('case 1');
            //check if startDate and endDate are valid
            if (startDate > endDate) {
                console.log('wmessage_container', wmessage_container);
                wmessage_container.show();
                $("#spinner").css('display', 'none');
                content.css('display', 'none');
                wmessage.text('start date and end date values are invalid!');
                console.log('startDate is bigger than end date');
            }
            else {
                var promise = dataFactory.getDGAList(startDate, endDate);
                wmessage_container.css('display', 'none');
                content.show();
               promise.then(function successCallback(response) {
                    // this callback will be called asynchronously
                    // when the response is available
                    console.log('success callback');
                    console.log('response.status ', response.status);
                    console.log('response.data', response.data);
                    console.log('response.headers', response.headers);
                    console.log('response.config', response.config);
                    $("#spinner").css('display', 'none');
                    if (response.status == 200) {
                        $scope.collection = response.data;
                    }

                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                    // or server returns response with an error status.
                    content.hide();
                    $("#spinner").css('display', 'none');
                    wmessage.text('No relevant Data found in requested dated ,\nPlease try other date range !');
                    wmessage_container.show();
                    console.log('error Callback');
                    console.log('response.data', response.data);
                    console.log('response.headers', response.headers);
                    console.log('response.config', response.config);
                });

            }

            //call DataFactory service.
        } else {

            wmessage_container.show();
            content.hide();
            $("#spinner").css('display', 'none');
            if ((startDate == '' || !angular.isDefined(startDate)) && (endDate == '' || !angular.isDefined(endDate))) {
                console.log('case 2');
                wmessage.text('start date and end date are required !');
            }
            else if (startDate == '' || !angular.isDefined(startDate)) {
                console.log('case 3');
                wmessage.text('start date is required !');
            } else {
                console.log('case 4');
                wmessage.text('end date is required !');
            }

        }

        console.log('startDate', startDate);
        console.log('endDate', endDate);

        $("#blackout").addClass("visable");
        $("#popup").addClass("visable");

    });

    $('#okbtn').click(function () {
        var selectedDGA = $scope.collection[$scope.selectedDga.index];
        $("#blackout").removeClass("visable");
        $("#popup").removeClass("visable");
        var promise = dataFactory.getDGASummary(selectedDGA["Id"]);
        promise.then(function successCallback(response) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
            console.log('success callback');
            console.log('response.status ', response.status);
            console.log('response.data', response.data);
            console.log('response.headers', response.headers);
            console.log('response.config', response.config);
            console.log('response.data[IEEE]'+response.data['IEEE']);
            generateIEEE(response.data['IEEE']);
            generateIEC(response.data['IEC']);
            generateCIGRE(response.data['CIGRE443']);
            generateTOA(response.data['TOA']);
            generateNEI(response.data['NEI']);
            generatePTX(response.data['PTX']);
            generateCOCO2Ratio(response.data['CoCo2Ratio']);
            generateDuvalTriangle(response.data['DuvalTriangle']);
            generateDuvalPentgons(response.data['DuvalPentagon']);
            var arr = response.data['DgaSample']['Results'];
            console.log('arr', arr);
            $scope.gases_table = arr;


        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
            console.log('promise callback');
            console.log('response.data', response.data);
            console.log('response.headers', response.headers);
            console.log('response.config', response.config);
        });
    });

    $('#cancelbtn').click(function () {
        $("#blackout").removeClass("visable");
        $("#popup").removeClass("visable");
    })
```

The css

```
#blackout {
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            opacity: 0;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            position: fixed;
            visibility: hidden;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
            transition: z-index 500ms, visibility 800ms, opacity 1000ms;
        }

        #blackout.visable {
            opacity: 1;
            z-index: 8;
            visibility: visible;
        }

        #popup {
            opacity: 0;
            top: -250px;
            left: -300px;
            width: 600px;
            height: 250px;
            padding: 15px;
            position: fixed;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin: -125px 0 0 50%;
            background: rgb(248, 248, 248);
            transition: top 550ms, opacity 500ms, z-index 500ms;
        }
        #popup.visable {
            top: 50%;
            opacity: 1;
            z-index: 9;
        }

        #popup .close {
            top: -10px;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            right: -10px;
            cursor: pointer;
            position: absolute;
            border-radius: 15px;
            background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            background-image: url(http://imgh.us/close_1.svg); /**TODO: transfer it to relative path**/
            background-size: contain;
        }


        #popup .close:hover {
            background-image: url(http://imgh.us/close_hover.svg); /**TODO: transfer it to relative path**/
        }

        #popup > #okbtn{
            position:absolute;
            bottom: 2%;
            right: 35%;
            width: 60px;
            cursor:pointer;
        }

        #popup > #cancelbtn{
            position:absolute;
            bottom: 2%;
            right: 50%;
            width: 60px;
            cursor:pointer;
        }
        #GoBtn{
            width: 60px;
        }

        #warning-message{
            position:absolute;
            padding:0;
            margin-top: 15%;
            width: 100%;
            padding-right: 30px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #wmessage{
            font-family:'Segue UI', Calibri, arial, verdana, sans-serif;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight:normal;
            margin:0;
            padding: 5px;
        }
```

Comment: I would like to get suggestions , regrading how to manage the code and organize it into directive or service properly.

Comment: I think you should start with how to write angular code without jquery thing. A lot of jquery part in your controller. For example you should use ng-click instead of $('#okbtn').click(function ()...

Comment: ok I will do it. any chance for example for modal directive?